# How to perform calculations with multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, integer, calculation

So I have 4 lists, 2 of them are created inside a function and 2 outside a function.

```
list_3 = []
list_4 = []
def create_list_3_4():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    list_3.append(a) 
    list_3.append(b)

    c = 8
    d = 9
    list_4.append(c)
    list_4.append(d)

    return list_3, list_4

list_1 = [10.5, 8.5]
list_2 = [12.6, 11.5]


value_1 = [x[0] for x in list_1] - [x[0] for x in list_2]
value_2 = [x[0] for x in create_list_3_4()] - [[x[0] for x in create_list_3_4()]]
value_3 = value_2 / value_1
new_list = []
new_list.append(value_3)
print(new_list)
```

For every Item in `list_2` I want to do minus every item in `list_1`. So `12.6 - 10.5` and `11.5 - 8.5` etc.. for the lists inside the function I want to do the same. So `8 - 4` and `9 - 5` etc...

Ultimately I want to divide the answer of `12.6 - 10.5` and `8 - 4` with each other and place that in
`new_list`.

**This is my current output:**

```
    value_1 = [x[0] for x in list_1] - [x[0] for x in list_2]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
[1.904, 1.333]
```

**Extra info for the calculations:**

```
1.904 = (8 - 4 = 4 / 12.6 - 10.5 = 2.1)
1.333 = (9 - 5 = 4 / 11.5 - 8.5 = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved through a list comprehension, as you've already started, as well as the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
list_1 = [10.5, 8.5]
list_2 = [12.6, 11.5]
value_1 = [num_2 - num_1 for num_1, num_2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

For the second part, you'll want to define `list_3` and `list_4` before the final comprehension:

```
list_3, list_4 = create_list_3_4()
value_2 = [num_2 - num_1 for num_1, num_2 in zip(list_3, list_4)]
```

And then divide the lists:

```
value_3 = [num_2 / num_1 for num_1, num_2 in zip(value_1, value_2)]
```

These steps can be combined to reduce runtime (although it isn't completely necessary if you want greater clarity):

```
value_3 = [(num_4 - num_3) / (num_2 - num_1) for num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4 in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)]
```

As a note, you may be better off using the [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) module if you intend on doing math with iterables, which allows for simplicity like so (assuming each of the lists has been converted to an array):

```
value_3 = (list_4 - list_3) / (list_2 - list_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to combine the four lists and perform the operation in a list comprehension:

```
def create_list_3_4():
    list_3 = []
    list_4 = []
    a = 4
    b = 5
    list_3.append(a) 
    list_3.append(b)

    c = 8
    d = 9
    list_4.append(c)
    list_4.append(d)

    return list_3, list_4

list_1 = [10.5, 8.5]
list_2 = [12.6, 11.5]
list_3,list_4 = create_list_3_4()

new_list = [(x4-x3)/(x2-x1) for x1,x2,x3,x4 in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3,list_4)]

print(new_list)
[1.904761904761905, 1.3333333333333333]
```

To perform operations between whole lists, you could/should use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

list_1 = np.array([10.5, 8.5])
list_2 = np.array([12.6, 11.5])
list_3,list_4 = map(np.array,create_list_3_4())

new_list = (list_4 - list_3) / (list_2 - list_1)

print(new_list)
[1.9047619  1.33333333]
```

*Note that you should initialize list_3 and list_4 inside the function otherwise you won't be able to use it more than once as it will add content every time it is called (making the lists larger and larger and incompatible with list_1 and list_2)*